# What is the Maximum Width an image can be in an Android Project? (Sprite Related Question)

Tags: java, android, image, animation, sprite

Hey guys currently the way I frame my sprites in my Android game requires all the sprite images to be in the same row.

Say I want to make a 100 frame sprite sheet that has a width of 50px/frame.. (5000px wide)

Can I load that into my project and use it? I remember programming in XNA Game Studio and it had issues with large images being used for sprites...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can be 420*380 for a phone but the image can have any width.